# How to add a class to an element after a group of elements (based on class) in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have a comment structure like this:

```
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
```

I want to add the class `last` to the last reply (after comment), so I did something like this:

```
$('.reply:last').addClass('last');
```

However, it only applies the `last` class to the `last` reply div. Is there a way to add the `last` class to the last reply after comment so it becomes this:

```
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="reply last"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply last"></div>
<div class="comment"></div>
<div class="reply"></div>
<div class="reply last"></div>
```

Thanks!

Also, would it be possible to make it work like this as well, where we have a reply on the top of the page? This could happen if I'm paging and a reply is show first.

```
<div class="comments">
    <div class="reply last"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="reply"></div>
    <div class="reply last"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="reply last"></div>
    <div class="comment"></div>
    <div class="reply"></div>
    <div class="reply last"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: do you want to add "last" to last reply of each comment?

Comment: Yep. I'm having trouble because the reply divs are separate from the comment divs. It's a design rule I have to stick with. I think it would be easier if I could wrap the replies inside another div, but it would break the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at jQuery's [.nextUntil()](http://api.jquery.com/nextuntil/). With it would could do the following:

```
$('.comment').each(function(){
    $(this).nextUntil('.comment').filter(':last').addClass('last');
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zu9cm/).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, that seems to work for the fist case. Is there a way to make this work if I have one or more replies on top (see last code section in question)? It is wrapped in the "Comments" div. Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out using this: $('.comments').find('.comment').first().prev('.reply').addClass('last')

Answer (score 0):

for first case use 
`$("body .comment:last-child .reply:last-child").addClass("last");`

for second case use

```
$("body").find(".comment").each(function(){
      $(this).find(".reply").last().addClass("last");
)};
```

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vpkqz/). I had moved all reply divs inside respective comments divs to use inheritance property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to just use the `not()` function. I tried this, have a look

```
$('.reply:last').addClass('last');
$('.reply').not($('.reply:last')).removeClass('last');
```

and a Fiddle sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6H7Ht/1/).